# Llamar accion de controlador con tres parametros desde ajax

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Les comento trabajo en VS2019 / Asp MVC 5 .net / C#.

Tengo una datatable con datos, y agregue un botón para llamar a una vista, pero tengo que enviar 3 parámetros, lo cual no logro realizar, ya que la acción del controlador no es llamada en el código que aquí les comparto, y cuando lograba llamar a la vista los parámetros recibidos por la acción del controlador llamado, recibía los valores con datos nulos. Aquí el código de mi script:

```
@section scripts{
<script>
    var dataTabledtMatSemestres;
    var cr_cve_gpo = $('#cr_cve_gpo').val();
    var cr_cve_mat = $('#cr_cve_mat').val();
    var cr_cve_car = $('#cr_cve_car').val();
    var cve_gpo;
    var cve_mat;
    var cve_car;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        dataTabledtMatSemestres = $("#dtMatDocentes").DataTable({
            //"serverSide": false,
            //"orderMulti": false,
            //"bFilter": true,
            //scrollY: '50vh',
            //scrollCollapse: true,

            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No se encontraron registros para mostrar.",
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
            },
            "responsive": "true",
            /*"dom": 'Bfrtilp',*/
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Captura/ListarGruposDelDocente",
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //"data": { cRpe: cRpe},
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "cr_cve_gpo" },
                { "data": "cr_cve_mat" },
                { "data": "cr_materia" },
                { "data": "cr_horario" },
                { "data": "cr_cve_car" },
                { "data": "cr_nombre_carrera" },
                {
                    "data": { cr_cve_gpo: cr_cve_mat, cr_cve_mat: cr_cve_mat, cr_cve_car: cr_cve_mat }, 
                    "orderable": false,
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        //var cRper = "22675";
                        //return "<button class='btn btn-primary AgregaRegBtn btn-xs d-print-none' data-backdrop='static' data-toggle='modal' data-id=" + data + " data-title=" + data + " data-cover_small=" + data + " data-target='#AgregaMateria' title='Clic para agregar la materia seleccionada...'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i> Agregar </button>";
                        return "<a onclick=VerAlumnos(" + data + ")  class='btn btn-secondary btn-xs d-print-none' title='Clic para visualizar grupo...'><i class='fas fa-search'></i> Visualizar </a>";
                    }
                }
            ]

        });

    });


    function VerAlumnos(data) {
        
        cve_gpo = data.cr_cve_gpo;
        cve_mat = data.cr_cve_mat;
        cve_car = data.cr_cve_car;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("VisualizarAlumnos", "Captura")/',
            data: "{cr_cve_gpo:" + cve_gpo + "cr_cve_mat:" + cve_mat + "cr_cve_car:" + cve_car + "}"
            });
    }
</script>
```

Este es el código de la acción del controlador llamado:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult VisualizarAlumnos(string cr_cve_gpo, string cr_cve_mat, string cr_cve_car)
    {
        //Declaración de VieModel
        ValidaFechaCapturaEvaluacion_ViewModel edoFechaCaptura = new ValidaFechaCapturaEvaluacion_ViewModel();
        List<tCalendarioExamen_ViewModel> ListaCalendarioCaptura = new List<tCalendarioExamen_ViewModel>();

        using (CalificacionesEntities bdC = new CalificacionesEntities())
        {
            //Parametros requeridos en el spValidaFechaCapturaEvaluacion 
            SqlParameter[] param_spValidaFechaCapturaEvaluacion = new SqlParameter[] {
                new SqlParameter ("@cTipoEvaluacion", "Parcial 2"),
                new SqlParameter ("@cic_esc", Session["s_ciclo"]),
                new SqlParameter ("@per_imp", Session["s_periodo"]),
                new SqlParameter ("@iValidaFechaCaptura", -1),
            };
            var cic_esc_var = Session["s_ciclo"].ToString();
            var per_imp_var = Session["s_periodo"].ToString();
            //Se ejecuta el spValidaFechaCapturaEvaluacion [Valida calendarización de fechas]
            edoFechaCaptura = bdC.Database.SqlQuery<ValidaFechaCapturaEvaluacion_ViewModel>("spValidaFechaCapturaEvaluacion @cTipoEvaluacion, @cic_esc, @per_imp, @iValidaFechaCaptura", param_spValidaFechaCapturaEvaluacion).SingleOrDefault();
            ViewBag.EdoFechaCaptura = edoFechaCaptura.iValidaFechaCaptura.ToString();

            //Generamos un lista con las fechas de evaluación
            ListaCalendarioCaptura = bdC.tCalendarioExamen.Where(x => x.cTipoEvaluacion == "Parcial 2" && x.cic_esc == cic_esc_var && x.per_imp == per_imp_var)
                                        .Select(tc_s => new tCalendarioExamen_ViewModel { id = tc_s.id, cTipoEvaluacion = tc_s.cTipoEvaluacion, dfecha_aplicar_inicio = tc_s.dfecha_aplicar_inicio, dfecha_aplicar_fin = tc_s.dfecha_aplicar_fin, dfecha_inicio = tc_s.dfecha_inicio, dfecha_fin = tc_s.dfecha_fin, cic_esc = tc_s.cic_esc, per_imp = tc_s.per_imp, iEdo = tc_s.iEdo })
                                        .ToList();
            ViewBag.Calendarizacion = ListaCalendarioCaptura;
        }

        using (EscolaresEntities bdE = new EscolaresEntities())
        {
            SqlParameter[] param_Calificaciones_sp_MuestraAlumnos = new SqlParameter[] {
                    new SqlParameter ("@cve_gpo", cr_cve_gpo),
                    new SqlParameter ("@cve_mat", cr_cve_mat),
                    new SqlParameter ("@cve_car", cr_cve_car)
                };
            //Se ejecuta el spListaGrupos 
            var Lista_Calificaciones_sp_MuestraAlumnos = bdE.Database.SqlQuery<alumnos_ViewModel>("Calificaciones_sp_MuestraAlumnos @cve_gpo, @cve_mat, @cve_car", param_Calificaciones_sp_MuestraAlumnos).ToList();

            //                return Json(new { data = Lista_Calificaciones_sp_MuestraAlumnos }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return View(Lista_Calificaciones_sp_MuestraAlumnos);
        }
    }
```

Agradeceria su orientación para realizar el llamado enviando los parametros...

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("VisualizarAlumnos", "Captura")/',
        data: {cr_cve_gpo: cve_gpo,cr_cve_mat:cve_mat,cr_cve_car:cve_car}
        });
```

Me gustaria saber que pensas hacer una vez que funcione la llamada, deberias agregar la funcionalidad en `succes:function(data){}`